# Put app on foreground programmatically on Swift

Tags: ios, swift, foreground

I tested:

```
UIControl().sendAction(#selector(URLSessionTask.suspend), to: UIApplication.shared, for: nil)
```

which is for putting app on background and it works.

How do I put app back on foreground?

I tried:

```
UIControl().sendAction(#selector(URLSessionTask.resume), to: UIApplication.shared, for: nil)
```

But eventually it crashes...

Thank you

Comment: This is an interesting hack to call the private `suspend` method on `UIApplication`. Of course if Apple realizes you are doing this your app may get rejected.

Comment: Really? Even though the app is for that? (app will not hide a thing...). Anyway, is there a way to do that?

Comment: As a user, I hope not, it would be extremely annoying

Comment: You can't move app to foreground programmatically, it's simply not allowed. You can do something like deep link / universal link, but it all should be user-initiated.

Comment: One other thing to realize, your code suspends your app, it doesn't just put it in the background. And once your app is suspended, it isn't running any more so it can't put itself in the foreground. You would need an external trigger such as some sort of notification.

Comment: It will be user initialized. This back/foreground thing iz user-defined. Is not going to be annoying due to is user-initialized.

Comment: Apps can be brought back to foreground only by user action (that triggers some programmatic actions true). It's by design this way (and I must say a very good design).

Comment: Did you get this working Amg91?

Comment: No... I don't know if I am missing something...

Answer (score 7):

**Update:**

Since you've indicated that you're looking for *any* technical solution, even those not compatible with the App Store or Apple's terms, this *should* be possible using the Private API `LSApplicationWorkspace: openApplicationWithBundleID`. Try something like this:

Create a .h file and set up an interface to the `LSApplicationWorkspace` class and list the required method. You will need to `#import "PrivateHeaders.h"` in your bridging header.

```
//
// PrivateHeaders.h
//

#ifndef PrivateHeaders_h
#define PrivateHeaders_h

@interface LSApplicationWorkspace : NSObject

- (bool)openApplicationWithBundleID:(id)arg1;

@end

#endif /* PrivateHeaders_h */
```

You should then be able to call this function and pass in the Bundle Identifier of your app as an string.

```
//
// SomeClass.swift
//

import MobileCoreServices

let workspace = LSApplicationWorkspace()

/**
 Launch an App given its bundle identifier
 - parameter bundleIdentifier: The bundle identifier of the app to launch
 - returns: True if app is launched, otherwise false
 */
func openApp(withBundleIdentifier bundleIdentifier: String) -> Bool {
    // Call the Private API LSApplicationWorkspace method
    return workspace.openApplication(withBundleID: bundleIdentifier)
}
```

**Original:**

What you are doing is likely a violation of the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/overview/themes/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH20-SW27) (although the "Don’t Quit Programmatically" is no longer specifically defined), so as the comments have said, it is not suited to the App Store. Regardless, once your app is suspended in this way, I don't expect that there is a way to resume it programmatically, unless you can hook into a [Background Operation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) to run `URLSessionTask.resume`, but I have not tested it and am unsure whether it can work.

Apps can be launched (and hence brought into the foreground) programmatically from another app or today extension by using a [Custom URL Scheme](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app), or via a [Push Notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH3-SW1). It isn't possible to launch the app from the Background Operation via a URL Scheme, since it is part of the UIKit framework, which must be run in the main thread.

In summary, I think your best option is to try to use a Notification. This just means that the user will need to click on the notification to bring your app back into the foreground.

Comment: the app is for that... I know it kinda violates guidelines, but is not an annoying app. On the app references would say that. The thing is, how? I tried using schemes, URLSessionTask.resume (crashes) and nothing works.

Comment: It doesn't just "kinda" violate the iOS HIG, it also definitely violates the [Apple Developer Program License Agreement](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Documentation/License_Agreements__Apple_Developer_Program/Apple_Developer_Program_License_Agreement_20180604.pdf). So to re-emphasize this: There is **no way** you will be able to sell this through the AppStore with the call you make in your code. I'm not saying this to be mean, just to save you from investing effort in something you won't be able to publish. If it's just a pet project, good luck playing arund! :)

Comment: Amg91, I have updated my answer with a Private API example that should do what you are want.

Comment: @JordanJohnson Hey, that's actually a nice find. :) To re-emphasize: This is code for _another_ app to bring the original app back to foreground. Code belonging to the target app obviously can't "bring itself back alive" if it is suspended (and OP's code does _suspend_ it). Suspended apps don't execute anything, so the "reanimating code" won't be executed either. Furthermore: This basically switches apps, but yoou won't be able to use it with an arbitrary timer if you plan on executing it in the background (because apps in background eventually get suspended as well, which stops all timers).

Comment: You're completely right Gero. I've assumed he will try to call it from some kind of [Background Operation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html). Amg91 hasn't outlined the exact 'trigger' for when the app would be brought back into the foreground, so I've assumed that it's within the constraints of whichever background operation he has chosen.

Amg91, just to confirm. Does your above method of suspending an app still allow for Background Operation?

Comment: I set the backgroundMode but does not bring back the app. Is something missing?

Comment: Hmm.. Are you able to verify that any of the code you are running in the background is actually executing?

Answer (score 1):

Closing/opening the app should be done explicitly by the user. Any other way of closing or opening the app is not supported by Apple and will be rejected when uploaded to app store. iOS Human Interface Guideline states:

> **Don’t Quit Programmatically**
>
> Never quit an iOS application
>   programmatically because people tend to interpret this as a crash.
>   However, if external circumstances prevent your application from
>   functioning as intended, you need to tell your users about the
>   situation and explain what they can do about it. Depending on how
>   severe the application malfunction is, you have two choices.
>
> *Display
>   an attractive screen that describes the problem and suggests a
>   correction. A screen provides feedback that reassures usersthat
>   there’s nothing wrong with your application. It puts usersin control,
>   letting them decide whether they want to take corrective action and
>   continue using your application or press the Home button and open a
>   different application
>
> *If only some of your application's features are
>   not working, display either a screen or an alert when people activate
>   the feature. Display the alert only when people try to accessthe
>   feature that isn’t functioning

Comment: This guideline might be specific to Quitting. I can see an Activate() method f the application was not running prior to calling activate(), it will be launched automatically.https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuiapplication/2873317-activate

Answer (score 0):

Just as a follow up to Jordan's excellent answer I want to give an explanation for why your code works in the first place and why that alone will get your app rejected, even without any functionality to make it active again and bring it to the foreground.

As maddy pointed out in a comment, you're basically calling a method from `UIApplication`'s private API. This works due to the Objective-C runtime's dynamic linking. You might wonder "But I am using Swift, what does that have to do with Objective-C?" The answer lies in `#selector` mechanism. A Selector is basically just a symbol that the Objective-C runtime looks up in a table to get a method it invokes (for you). This is why it's technically not correct to say you "call a method" when you do something like `myObjectInstance.someMethod()`. The correct way to phrase that would be to "send a message" to the object, because that's what is happening in the runtime. The target-action mechanism is build around that. The `sendAction(_: Selector?, to: Any?)` method does the same thing. So in effect your code does the following:

1. Get the symbol that corresponds to `URLSessionTask`'s `suspend()` method.
2. Tell the `shared` instance of `UIApplication` to invoke the method that ***it*** has for that symbol.

Now usually that would result in a crash with the typical "unknown selector sent to instance..." error message. But here, by sure coincidence `UIApplication` *also* has a method for that instance (or rather, the runtime also has one of its methods listed in its table for that symbol). You kind of "found" a method that is not declared in its public header. You successfully circumvented a compile-time check for this and invoke a method that is part of a *private API*. This is explicitly forbidden in the [Apple Developer Program License Agreement](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Documentation/License_Agreements__Apple_Developer_Program/Apple_Developer_Program_License_Agreement_20180604.pdf)

Besides all that, I would strongly advise against trying to design an app that way in the first place. As maddy pointed out it's also likely considered to violate the HIGs. Even if you're not trying to do anything malicious and properly explain the feature in your app's description, that won't make Apple let it slide (I assume). Personally, as a user, I'd also find it annoying if the app did something the system already has a specific mechanic for in a different manner, at least in terms of app's coming to background and foreground.

Comment: ok, so you guys are saying that is technically not possible? I know the license agreement and all that, the things was more if it was possible and how to do that.

Comment: _Technically_ it is possible, as Jordan explained in his answer. As I said I just wanted to elaborate on how it's working and what the consequences in regards to your chances of successfully submitting it to the AppStore are.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done without user interaction

The option is you can generate a push notification to tell the user to bring the application to foreground

When the operating system delivers push notification and the target application is not running in the foreground, it presents the notification.

If there is a notification alert and the user taps or clicks the action button (or moves the action slider), the application launches and calls a method to pass in the local-notification object or remote-notification payload.